# PowerShell: Set-Acl "SeSecurityPrivilege" authorization missing

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a PowerShell script which should change the permissions of a file:

```
param([string] $Path)\
$Berechtigung = Get-ACL -Path $Path\
$Berechtigung.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)\
$NEUBerechtigung = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(“TEST\Domain-users”,”Read,ReadAndExecute”,”Allow”)\
$Berechtigung.SetAccessRule($NEUBerechtigung)\
$Berechtigung | Set-Acl -Path $Path
```

The PowerShell script is getting started with a batch-file which is passing a data-path to the script and runs it as an administrator:

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -File .\Powershell_komplett.ps1 -path ""C:\_TEST\Erlaubt.txt""\
PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\_TEST\Powershell_komplett.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

When I execute the batch-file I get the following error:

> The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.

How can I bypass this?

Comment: I assume the user which is running this command does not have enough rights. As the error message tells, it's missing the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/manage-auditing-and-security-log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to restrict a group's access to a file but I was in the group myself. Since I am also an administrator on my device, I have full access to the file and therefore nothing has changed for me. So I added a group that I myself am not a member of and then it worked. Thanks for your help